# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener() is called twice

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension and in some web sites chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener() is called twice.

It mostly happens if i click on a link and not when i type in a URL by myself.

From what i found on the web and from many questions asked on StackOverflow there was a bug on chrome but it was fixed several years ago.

Some people claim it happens if there are several iframes in the page, but in my case there are no iframes in my page.

This is my code:

```
 var storage = chrome.storage.local;

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.status == 'complete' && tab.url != undefined) {
            storage.get('URLs', function(URLs){
                for (var item in URLs)
                {
                    if (tab.url == item)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //alert ("tab load complete");
                        storage.set({URLs: [tab.url]});
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                        "file": "flashblocker.js"
                        }, function () { // Execute your code
                        console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    }
});
```

How can i make it run only once?

Thanks.

Comment: onUpdated could be called when history API is called or just '#foo' hash changed.  I think you need to use @Nikhil 's method below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a variable and add a check inside the listener to check the value of this variable before executing the alert. You can do something like this:

```
var tabUpdated = false;
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.status == 'complete' && tab.url != undefined) {
        if (!tabUpdated) {
            alert("tab load complete");
            tabUpdated = true;
        }
    }
});
```

But this will fail if the content script is actually loading twice as the tabUpdated variable will again be initialized to false. In that case you can use the chrome's Storage API and store the URL for which the listener has been already invoked. Simply add a check for this, if the URL is there in storage, the alert wont be invoked, else it will invoke. You can then clear the storage at the browser start or close.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.status == 'complete' && tab.url != undefined) {
        chrome.local.storage.get('URLs', function(URL's) {
            // Iterate through this list here and match with tab.url, if the match is found, just return.
            if (url is there in list) {return;}
            else {
                alert("tab load complete");
                chrome.local.set({URLs: [tab.url]}); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is just an example of how you can achieve it. Tweak it according to your needs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nikhil thanks for your comment. It works with alert("") but the problem is I'm trying to run a script (I've updated my answer with the code) and the script still runs twice.
Any idea?

Comment: Yes, because you are replacing the old URL with the new one. Just add new URL to the old URLs array and then save using `storage.set()`. Store the URLs you get using `storage,get()` to a variable first and then in the else block add new URL to this array and then save. Sorry I forgot to add the code that  way in my answer. Just try it this way. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, just use a variable to store result of whether a match is found or not and then use this variable for if else block outside the `for loop`. Use break instead of return. Can you think why it should not be checked inside the loop..??

Comment: I'm new to JS and have no idea why not to do this inside the loop. For now i'm trying to understand how to add the tab.url to the list of URLS :)
Why should it be done inside the loop?